# Fill stock input in searchbox on moneycontrol site using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to fetch `stock` information from `Moneycontrol site`. I want to fill stock name in `searchbox`.
html code:

```
<input class="txtsrchbox FL" id="search_str" 
      onkeyup="getAutosuggesionHeader('#form_topsearch');" 
      onclick="getAutosuggesionHeader('#form_topsearch');" 
      placeholder="Search Quotes, News, NAVs" name="search_str" 
      value="" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

How can i achieve this using `beautifulsoup`.

I have tried following code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

import urllib

post_params = {'value' : 'SBIN' }

post_args = urllib.parse.urlencode(post_params).encode("utf-8")

url = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com'

fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url, post_args)

soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)
```

Comment: What data specifically are you wanting to retrieve?

Comment: i want to fetch sbin moneycontrol page.i want to open sbi page when entering sbin to searchbox. Like this other stocks also

Comment: State bank of India?

Comment: Yes state bank of india

Comment: Can you give one other search term please?

Comment: reliance industries or bharti airtel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with financial info so this might not be of use, but maybe it is, or maybe QHarr can work off of it. Looks like it gives back some value for (t:time?, cp:closing price? v:volume? ap:???)

So I noticed you can get some response from the chart data, however it requires to enter a parameter to query (ie. a sc_id value, in this case for SBIN, is SBI.)

So I needed a way though to get that sc_id value, and saw they have a "suggested" text search return that can be accessed to enter your search word (ie: "sbin"), to get back that sc_id.

So here's a little script that was able to get some info back for SBIN. Hopefully this can get some use out of it:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36'}


# Enter search text
query_input = input('Enter Search Text: ')

#Get suggested sc_id
suggest_query_url = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/mccode/common/autosuggestion_solr.php'

query = {
'classic': 'true',
'query': query_input,
'type': '1',
'format': 'json',
'callback': 'suggest1'}


# Pull out the sc_id
suggested_response = requests.get(suggest_query_url , headers=headers, params=query).text
suggested_response = suggested_response.split('(',1)[1]
suggested_response = suggested_response.rsplit(')',1)[0]

sc_id = json.loads(suggested_response)[0]['sc_id']


# Use the sc_id to get BSE and NSE data
request_url = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/company_info/get_vwap_chart_data.php'
query = {'sc_did': sc_id}

response = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers, params=query).json()
```

**Output:**

```
print (response)
{'BSE': [{'t': '1551949665', 'ap': '279.70', 'cp': '279.70', 'v': '2151'}, {'t': '1551949704', 'ap': '279.70', 'cp': '279.70', 'v': '2151'}, {'t': '1551949740', 'ap': '279.70', 'cp': '279.70', 'v': '2151'}, {'t': '1551950159', 'ap': '278.93', 'cp': '278.90', 'v': '18755'}, {'t': '1551950219', 'ap': '278.90', 'cp': '278.70', 'v': '23368'}, {'t': '1551950279', 'ap': '278.89', 'cp': '279.00', 'v': '32498'}, {'t': '1551950338', 'ap': '278.91', 'cp': '279.00', 'v': '36396'}, {'t': '1551950399', 'ap': '278.90', 'cp': '278.80', 'v': '42964'}, {'t': '1551950459', 'ap': '278.88', 'cp': '278.35', 'v': '45685'}, {'t': '1551950519', 'ap': '278.76', 'cp': '278.30', 'v': '54082'}, {'t': '1551950579', 'ap': '278.74', 'cp': '278.30', 'v': '56780'}, {'t': '1551950639', 'ap': '278.69', 'cp': '278.20', 'v': '62504'}, {'t': '1551950699', 'ap': '278.68', 'cp': '278.10', 'v': '63338'}, {'t': '1551950759', 'ap': '278.68', 'cp': '278.10', 'v': '63723'}, {'t': '1551950819', 'ap': '278.67', 'cp': '277.80', 'v': '64998'}, {'t': '1551950879', 'ap': '278.63', 'cp': '278.20', 'v': '68780'}, {'t': '1551950939', 'ap': '278.59', 'cp': '278.60', 'v': '77680'}, {'t': '1551950999', 'ap': '278.59', 'cp': '278.35', 'v': '79316'}, {'t': '1551951059', 'ap': '278.58', 'cp': '278.30', 'v': '80566'}, {'t': '1551951119', 'ap': '278.58', 'cp': '278.20', 'v': '81247'}, {'t': '1551951178', 'ap': '278.57', 'cp': '278.10', 'v': '82067'}, {'t': '1551951238', 'ap': '278.57', 'cp': '278.15', 'v': '82918'}, {'t': '1551951294', 'ap': '278.56', 'cp': '278.60', 'v': '85734'}, {'t': '1551951358', 'ap': '278.56', 'cp': '278.40', 'v': '87239'}, {'t': '1551951419', 'ap': '278.56', 'cp': '278.25', 'v': '88039'}, ...
```

Comment: if you know the industry (banking etc) you can combine that with the id to pass in a url query string to get info from indiv pages I think. I was looking earlier but am on course at moment.

Comment: actually i want to fetch stock's news..my idea was to soup monecontrol site then directly giving sbin  or state bank of india parameter to input text value...